# Nonstandard support function for the Busemann function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional complete Riemannian manifold.
Assume that $M$ contains a ray $\gamma : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $b_\gamma$ be the associated Busemann function, i.e.,
$$
b_\gamma(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}(d(x, \gamma(t) - t).
$$

The Busemann function in general is not smooth. We only know that it is continuous. Let $p \in M$ and let $\tilde{\gamma}$ be another ray starting from $p$ and constructed by using $\gamma$. (In his **Riemannian Geometry** book, Petersen calls it the *asymptote for $\gamma$ from $p$*). It is common to introduce the following support function from above for $b_\gamma$ at $p$:
$$
b_t(x) \,=\, d(x, \tilde{\gamma}(t)) \,- \,t \,\, + b_\gamma(p).
$$
For every $t >0$, this is indeed a support function from above at $p$ for $b_\gamma$ because $b_t$ is smooth around $p$ and

1. $b_t(q) = b_\gamma(q)$;
2. $b_t (x) \ge b_\gamma(x)$ in a neighbourhood of $p$.

In the literature, I found just this family of support function for $b_\gamma$, but I am dealing with a problem where I need something else. 
For example, it would be extremely desirable that the following family of functions are a family of support functions:
$$
b_t^*(x) = \frac{1}{t} \Big( d(x, \tilde\gamma(t)) - t\Big)  + b_\gamma(t).
$$
But I can't prove that the second property holds.

> Essentially I need a family of support functions where the only term where appears $x$ is of the kind 
>   $$
> \frac{K}{t^\alpha}d(x, \tilde\gamma(t)),
> $$ 
>   where $K$ is a positive constant and $\alpha \in (0, 1]$.

Any help or suggestion would be extremely appreciated.